# Converting Timeszones in PHP

Tags: php, time, timezone

I have a script that brings in RSS feeds that come from different timezones. I then publish the RSS feeds with a twitter style time display saying "posted about 10 minutes ago". But because I cant convert these times into my GMT timezone this display shows the wrong time eg a post from EST always says "about 5 hours ago" when it is new.

I have looked around to find solutions but none of them seem to work for me I wonder if you can tell me where I am going wrong.

```
$dbTimezone = new DateTimeZone($dbStoredTimezone); //$dbStoredTimezone = 'EST'
$dbDate = new DateTime($dbStoredDate, $dbTimezone); //$dbStoredDate = '2012-03-01 05:27:26'
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
echo $gmtTimezone->getOffset($dbDate); //always echo's 0
$offset = DateInterval::createFromDateString ($gmtTimezone->getOffset($dbDate));
$dbDate->add($offset);
```

Comment: read the red box here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Comment: Hmmm that may be a problem because the RSS feed pubDate uses the timezone format of EST

Comment: Still no change when I hard code EST to be America/New_York and GMT to be Europe/London

Comment: not like that set like this define('TZ_TIMEZONE', 'America/New_York');date_default_timezone_set(TZ_TIMEZONE);

Comment: Do RSS time fields contain time zone information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your `$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');`. Because `getOffset()` returns the offset from GMT (see here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php). This is exactly why it always returns `0`.

If you use the `DateTime::getOffset()` method it should work.

Here's your edited code:

```
<?php
$dbTimezone = new DateTimeZone($dbStoredTimezone); //$dbStoredTimezone = 'EST'
$dbDate = new DateTime($dbStoredDate, $dbTimezone);
echo $dbDate->getOffset();
$offset = DateInterval::createFromDateString ($dbDate->getOffset());
$dbDate->add($offset);
```

My result is `-18000`.

Comment: Wicked thanks a lot dude that was it. I also had to change how I got the DateInterval object to `$offset = new DateInterval('PT' . str_replace('-', '', $dbDate->getOffset()) . 'S');`. But I think this solution is a bit hacky though